# issues while serializing to YAML file

Tags: yamldotnet

I have started using .net API for yaml and it seems to be helpful. However I have few questions and wondering if you can provide some sample/work around for the same.
(1) I have an object consisting 4 strings I would like to serialize its collection (List or String[]). I wrote a helper method to return me the strings in the format I want, however it adds an extra single quote before and after the string. So I am getting

```
  -'{str1: str2, str3: str4}'
  -'{str5: str6, str7: str8}'
```

instead of

```
  -{str1: str2, str3: str4}
  -{str5: str6, str7: str8}
```

Can you suggest any workarounds?

(2) I am trying to insert xaml as a string in a yaml document. My xaml is well formed xml but when I serialize it, it cuts before 3rd last element. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question, if you are serializing an array of strings, then it is normal that each element is quoted because it starts with a '{'. In this case, you should be serializing the list of objects directly instead of converting them to string first.

Regarding the second question, you should add some code to the question to clarify what you are doing.